# Email send from website page - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have this method:

```
@api.model
def send_mail_function(self):
    template_id = self.env.ref('opencloud_cashflows.email_template_loan')
    if template_id:
       template_id.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
    return True
```

I call this from a website page like this:

```
<center><input id="send_mail_function" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="send_mail_function" value="Pedir préstamo al Banco" type="submit" style="background-color:#e67e22;"/></center>
```

But it doesn't do anything, is there something else I need to do to call this method from frontend/website on Odoo?

I'm on Odoo v9 community.

**EDIT**

This method is on `model` file, not on controller, ie `main.py`, could that be the issue?

But then, I think I cannot call `@api.model` decorator on Odoo controller file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be on `main.py` file. From `controller` you call this method. And please try with `@api.multi`

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but still nothing, are you sure this works without any javascript?

Comment: I have not used any javascript for this but it worked for me